# Does force chilling have the same effect as regular chilling as far as carbonation absorption is concerned?

Tags: carbonation, chilling, chemistry

I have a "Maytag Handy Chiller" - it's a great kitchen tool for chilling a bottle of wine in a few minutes which works buy circulating ice water over a bottle ( and optionally rotating it too ) to get the liquid down to drinking temp in a few minutes. We got it free with our fridge when we bought it - the kind of thing I'd never fork out for but I love it for the many times it's enabled consumption under non ideal circumstances :-) — basically it works great and chills the beer /white wine etc right down really fast and doesn't seem to screw with the taste in any way that I've noticed.

Anyway, since I started homebrewing I've used it more than I had in the past when I suddenly figured I'd sample a bottle that was actually still meant to be in conditioning. My question is this ... I know that beer absorbs CO2 during refrigeration but does anyone know whether this absorption is this related more to temperature, or to time at that temperature.

Will force chilling like this have a similar effect on carbonation absorption as if I had left it in the fridge overnight ( because it basically seems to have roughly that effect on the temperature )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dissolving CO<sub>2</sub> takes time. Area of contact between gas and liquid in bottle is really small. Thus, I doubt that few minutes would really help carbonate much. Of course, this is not totally pointless. By chilling fast, you can maximize time at optimal temperature. But use this as a step before putting bottle to fridge for a night, not instead.

Last but not least: **try**. Have one bottle in the fridge for a night or few days, and speed chill another bottle. Then, pour both and try both. No amount of theory and advice will ever substitute for one experiment and personal experience.

Comment: yes you're so right - must do that - I suppose I was just wondering if it was information in the common knowledge but it's an easy experimment to do - thanks

Answer (score 2):

It's related to both....given cold and warm temps and the same amount of time, the cold liquid will absorb more.   Same temp, more time for CO2 to dissolve into solution, the one with more time will have better carbonation.

Comment: OP is talking about the same temperature, different time. You are describing the same time, different temperature... what's the use?

Comment: Sorry, my answer got truncated.  Same temp, more time for CO2 to dissolve into solution, the one with more time will have better carbonation.